# No funciona mi paginación en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, paginación

Archivo esta relacionado con Categoria, el cual tiene relacion con un menu(clave foranea en cat) para filtrar los archivos. Entonces al paginarlos intento que sean filtrados por categoria y por el menu en que se identifica.

archivo(cat_id FK)->categoria(ruta_id FK)->ruta

Tengo la siguiente funcion en un controlador de archivos el cual quiero paginar en la vista principal.

```
    public function searchByCat($cat_id, $ruta_id){
    $archivos = Archivo::all();//->paginate(10);
    $categorias = Categoria::where('tipo_id',$ruta_id)->get();
    $filtroCategorias = Categoria::where('tipo_id',$ruta_id)->where('categoria_id',$cat_id)->get();
    $archivosAux = array();
    foreach($filtroCategorias as $cat){
      foreach($archivos as $file){
        if($file->cod_categoria==$cat->categoria_id){
          array_push($archivosAux,$file);
        }
      }
    }
    $archivos = $archivosAux;//->paginate(10);
    return view('archivos.index',compact('archivos','categorias','ruta_id'));
  }
 }
```

Mi problema es que al intentar de varias formas incluir el metodo paginate() no lo reconoce y me tira error. Soy algo nuevo en este framework.(Pensaba traducir el filtro de archivos a una sentencia sql con join entre las posibilidades)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estás aprovechando la funcionalidad de Laravel y Eloquent, veo que tienes relacionados los archivos con las categorías, por lo cual puedes fácilmente paginar los resultados.

El método paginate no te funciona actualmente porque intentas aplicarlo a un array, mientras dicho método en Laravel es para las colecciones de Eloquent.

No entiendo muy bien el resultado que deseas mostrar, pero muy probablemente encuentres la solución en los métodos disponibles de Eloquent y sus colecciones, mientras tanto revisa Eager Loading para cargar los archivos relacionados con cada categoría:

```
Categoria::with('archivos')
    ->where('tipo_id',$ruta_id)
    ->where('categoria_id',$cat_id)
    ->get();
```

Revisa los siguientes enlaces:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections

Comment: ¿Funcionó esta respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de la siguiente forma:

```
$archivos   = RutaTipo::select('archivos.archivo_id','archivos.desc_archivo',
    'archivos.nombre_fis_archivo','archivos.nombre_log_archivo','archivos.tamano_archivo',
    'archivos.version_archivo','archivos.docto_fis_archivo','docto_log_archivo',
    'marca_destacado','nro_descargas')
    ->join('categorias','ruta_tipos.ruta_tipo_id','=','categorias.tipo_id')
    ->join('archivos','categorias.categoria_id','=','archivos.cod_categoria')
    ->where('ruta_tipos.ruta_tipo_id',$ruta_id)->paginate(10);
```

Aun en mi poca experiencia sigo investigando para optimizar esto, aprovechando las funcionalidades de laravel de la siguiente forma(Sugerido por el usuario Sergio Kaznowiecki):

```
$archivos = RutaTipo::select('*')
      ->whereHas('categorias', function($query){
          $query->whereHas('archivos');
      })->with(['categorias' => function($query){
          $query->with('archivos:desc_archivo,nombre_fis_archivo,nombre_log_archivo,tamano_archivo,version_archivo,docto_fis_archivo');
          }])
      ->whereRutaTipoId($ruta_id)->paginate();
```